# Code compiles but does not run

Tags: java, swing

This is a simple calculator; my code compiles but is not working. I mean it does not Execute or Run:

```
   import java.awt.*;
   import javax.swing.*;
   import java.awt.event.*;
   public class Calc implements ActionListener{

JFrame frame;
JButton plus,mul;
JTextField op1,op2,ans;
JLabel firstOperand, secondOperand,answer;
// setting layout

public void initGUI(){

frame = new JFrame();////set top level container
Container con = frame.getContentPane();         
con.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

firstOperand = new JLabel("First Operand");g their constructor
secondOperand = new JLabel("Second Operand");
answer = new JLabel("Answer");

plus = new JButton("+");
plus.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(70,25));
mul = new JButton("*");
mul.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(70,25));

con.add(firstOperand); 
con.add(op1);r

con.add(secondOperand);
con.add(op2);

con.add(plus);
con.add(mul);

con.add(answer);
con.add(ans);


plus.addActionListener(this);
mul.addActionListener(this);

// set size of frame and make it visible
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setSize(200,220);
 frame.setVisible(true);

 }//end of initilization GUI

//constructor 
public Calc(){

initGUI();// jab obj create ho ga to call ho ga


}
// actionperformed() method of ActionListener

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){

      String oper, result;
    int num1,num2,res;
    //System.out.println(event.getSource);
    if(event.getSource() == plus){
    oper = op1.getText();
    oper = op2.getText();
    num2 = Integer.parseInt(oper);
    res = num1 + num2;//add operands
    result = res+"";
    ans.setText(result);
    }
    else if (event.getSource() == mul){
    oper = op1.getText();
    num1 = Integer.parseInt(oper);
    oper = op2.getText();
    num2 = Integer.parseInt(oper);
    res = num1 * num2;//add operands 
    result = res+"";
    ans.setText(result);

    }


}// end of actionPerformed method

public static void main(String args[]){

Calc cl = new Calc();// making object for Cals class

}
}
```

Comment: What error does it give?

Comment: This needs more diagnostics. What does "not execute" mean? Does it run at all? (If not, it probably did not compile, even though you think it did.) Does it run but nothing happens? Then add debug output to see it runs at all -- add a print statement right at the start.

Comment: Always look at the logs first. Its causing `java.lang.NullPointerException`

Answer (score 1):

Your JTextFields are not initialized. Initialize them with

```
op1 = new JTextField();
....
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `NullPointerException` because the `JTextFields` are not initialized. So when you try to add them to the `ControlPanel`, its throwing `NullPointerException`. Initialize them properly

Answer (score 0):

Add this your constructor :

```
  op1 = new JTextField();
  op2 = new JTextField();
  ans = new JTextField();
```